# How Piggybacking suppress duplicate segments?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, computer-science

I want to know the detailed explanation, means the mechanism that how Piggybacking suppresses duplicate segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the basic definition of Piggybacking, It is a technique used in networking protocols to optimize the transmission data and control information. By the combination of ACK packet and data packet within a single transmission it actually helps to reduce overhead and improve efficiency of data transfer.
And in your question mentioned, yes it is one of the benefit of piggybacking is its ability to suppress duplicate segment which results in unnecessary retransmission.

Piggybacking suppressed duplicate segments by by combination of acknowledgements for received data with the latest data it wants to send, the benefit of this is it ensures that the sender receives both acknowledgement and new/latest data in a single packet, preventing retransmission.

I hope you got the answer.